# Algorithm prints length of string rather than number of Cs and Gs in it

Tags: java

I am new to Java and currently learning it in a 4 week course. I am working on on an assignment to find all of the Cs and Gs in a string named dna, and then divide the number of Cs and Gs by dna. I have written a small program, and it compiles with no syntax errors, but when I run it, all that is printed out is the length of dna and then 1(The output of the dividing part).

My code:

```
public static void cgRatio (String dna) {
    int counter = 0; // counts how many Cs and Gs
    int index = 0; // start looking from index 0
    while (dna.indexOf("C") != -1 && counter != dna.length()) { // while dna is not finished and you can find C in dna
        index = dna.indexOf("C", index); // Start looking from last index
        if (index != -1) {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of C in dna: " + counter);

    System.out.println("Gene cg ratio: " + (counter / dna.length()));
}
```

If anyone can help that would be great and appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes, your code is doing what you wrote. So where's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument to [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) is the first index in the string that it searches.

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character, **starting the search at the specified index**.

Once it finds the first "C", it will then continue to always find that same "C" in the first index it looks in. You need to change your code to this:

```
index = dna.indexOf("C", index + 1);
```

To start from the first character *after* the "C" that you already found. You should also change the initial index to `-1` so that it starts from the first character.

Comment: I made the change as you described (using his code) and this change will end up missing one of the "Cs" in the string.

Comment: @JohnG ah, you're right. (I think) it only misses it if "C" is the first character. I updated my answer to correct that problem.

Comment: If I start index at -1 won't it break the while loop?

Comment: @WindowBreaker It should be fine, since the condition in your `while` is based on the `indexOf` call, and not `index` itself. (honestly, I don't think that condition in the `while` is actually needed. You could remove it completely).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- It uses `counter` as the number of `c`s in your dna string when it is really equal to `dna.length()`. This causes the ratio to be `1` if there are any `c`s at all, or `0` if there are none.
- There should be a variable that keeps track of how many `c`s there are in the string and how many `g`s there are (as seen in the above bullet, `counter` cannot be used for this.)
- As resueman said, this line:
  `index = dna.indexOf("C", index);` should be changed to: `index = dna.indexOf("C", index + 1);`, or else the index will remain the same (it will always be equal to the index of the first `c` in the string.)
- A `while loop` really is not all that well suited to this kind of thing; instead, a `for loop` should be used.
- The ratio should be a `double`, not an `int` since `double`s have more precision (they can be decimals.)

Here's code I came up with that works:

```
public static void cratio(String dna) {
    int c = 0;
    int g = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < dna.length(); i++) {
        if((dna.charAt(i) == 'c') || (dna.charAt(i) == 'C')) c++;
        if((dna.charAt(i) == 'g') || (dna.charAt(i) == 'G')) g++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of 'C's in DNA: " + c + " and number of 'G's in DNA: " + g);
    int length = dna.length();
    double ratio = (double) (c+g)/length * 100;
    System.out.println("The ratio of 'C's and 'G's to the length of the DNA chain is: " + ratio + "%.");
}
```

If you have any questions, just let me know!